# Kotlin to java conversion DefaultConstructorMarker is not public in kotlin.jvm.internal

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I Downloaded a kotlin file from github and wanted to convert it to a java file. I did this by Tools>Kotlin>Show kotlin ByteCode and then Decompiling. The Kotlin File is below:

```
 package io.pokemon.core
 import io.pokemon.model.Card
 import io.pokemon.util.random.Randomiser
 import io.pokemon.viewmodel.Round

 class RoundFactoryImpl(private val randomiser: Randomiser) : RoundFactory {
   override fun buildRound(cards: List<Card>): Round = Round() 
 }
```

After Copying the Decompiled kotlin Code into a java file I got the error: DefaultConstructorMarker is not public in kotlin.jvm.internal; cannot be accessed from outside package.

I attempted to fix this by adding the code inside DefaultConstructorMarker However this failed to fix the error.

```
package io.pokemon.core;
import io.pokemon.model.Card;
import io.pokemon.util.random.Randomiser;
import io.pokemon.viewmodel.Round;
import java.util.List;
import kotlin.Metadata;
import kotlin.jvm.internal.DefaultConstructorMarker;
import kotlin.jvm.internal.Intrinsics;
import org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull;

@Metadata(
...
)
public final class RoundFactoryImpl implements RoundFactory {
    private final Randomiser randomiser;

   @NotNull
   public Round buildRound(@NotNull List cards) {
      Intrinsics.checkParameterIsNotNull(cards, "cards");
      return new Round((List)null, (Card)null, 3, (DefaultConstructorMarker)null);
  }

  public RoundFactoryImpl(@NotNull Randomiser randomiser) {
      super();
      Intrinsics.checkParameterIsNotNull(randomiser, "randomiser");
      this.randomiser = randomiser;
  }
}
```

Comment: Any particular reason you need to re implement the file in Java? You could always make a java class that just implements the kotlin class, or just use the kotlin class from java.

Comment: the class `import kotlin.jvm.internal.DefaultConstructorMarker;` is kind of "package private" the "default" from java, probably is defined as internal on the original kotlin source code